# Resize canvas to viewport without loosing quality

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, viewport

I am trying to have a canvas fill the entire viewport and resize, whenever the user resizes the browser window.
However, when I try to use a size of `100%`, it looses quality.

I am kind of a newb in JavaScript programming.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Canvas is like a digital paper. You can resize the paper, but that doesn't change the content drawn upon it. You can zoom in on it, but, as you've already experienced, that'll cause quality loss. The only way to resize a canvas without quality loss would be to redraw the canvas content upon a resize event or some kind of update loop. Obviously the script that draws the content should adept to the new size for this to work properly.

Comment: second @icecubs comment, Unless you are using a vector such as a `svg`

Comment: @MichaelMano Agreed, but svg is not canvas :) With just canvas, you have none of the scaling.

Comment: Ok, I have already implemented a resize event, that also resizes the Canvas (with `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`, but I want the content to be correctly scaled, what can I do about that?

Comment: @weisbrja You have to clean and redraw to the new scale. You can use: `setTransform()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way:

I calculate a scaling factor, by which I scale the size, but not the position of each element drawn.
I do not want to scale the position, because then some elements might be off screen.
Thus I can not use `setTransform`, as suggested in the comments.
Here is the code I used for calculating the scaling factor.
If someone has improvements, please share them in the comments below!

```
if (window.screen.width > window.screen.height)
    scalingFactor = window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio / 1280;
else
    scalingFactor = window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio / 720;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here, but if you are using  `scalingFactor` you are definitely using a `transform` that you could probably use `setTransform` for. But your answer is incomplete without _showing us how you use the scalingFactor_ to solve the problem you were having.

Comment: @somethinghere It is very complicated to use a `transform`, because I do not want the positions to be scaled. I just want the sizes to be scaled. I just multiply every width and height or radius by this `scalingFactor`, whenever I need to draw something.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to resize a canvas with losing the data currently on it is to store the data, then resize the canvas (which clears it), then redraw the data into the canvas. That would look something like this:

```js
const data = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;
ctx.putImageData( data, 0, 0 );
```

In its purest, simplest example it would look something like this:

```js
/* This method does the resize by storing the data and redrawing it. It loses any data outside of the screen, though. */
function onResize( event ){

  const data = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
  
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
  
  ctx.putImageData( data, 0, 0 );

}

/* This method is for drawing some content to help visualisation. */
function onRedraw(){
    
  const r = v => Math.floor(Math.random() * v);
  
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;

  ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${r(255)},${r(255)},${r(255)})`;
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight );
  ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${r(255)},${r(255)},${r(255)})`;
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2 );
  ctx.fillRect( innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2, innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2 );

}

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onResize );

const canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
const reset = document.getElementById( 'reset' );

document.body.appendChild( canvas );

onRedraw();

redraw.addEventListener( 'click', onRedraw );
```

```css
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
button { position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 20px; z-index: 1; }
```

```html
<button id="redraw">Redraw</button>
```

However, you lose data drawn outside the canvas when your window grows and shrinks, as the data is never saved. We could hold a buffer with our graphics, which could simplify things a bit but makes the code slightly more complicated. In this case, we can use a second canvas that holds all our previously drawn maximum sized screen data, just for reference:

```js
/* This method does the resize by storing the data and redrawing it. It retains data outside the screen in a buffer that holds the maximum size ever drawn. */
function onResize( event ){

  const data = bufferCtx.getImageData( 0, 0, bufferCanvas.width, bufferCanvas.height );
  
  bufferCanvas.width = Math.max( bufferCanvas.width, innerWidth );
  bufferCanvas.height = Math.max( bufferCanvas.height, innerHeight );
  
  bufferCtx.putImageData( data, 0, 0 );
  bufferCtx.drawImage( canvas, 0, 0 );
  
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
  
  ctx.drawImage( bufferCanvas, 0, 0 );

}

/* This method is for drawing some content to help visualisation. */
function onRedraw(){
    
  const r = v => Math.floor(Math.random() * v);
  
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;

  ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${r(255)},${r(255)},${r(255)})`;
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight );
  ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${r(255)},${r(255)},${r(255)})`;
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2 );
  ctx.fillRect( innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2, innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2 );

}

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onResize );

const canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
const bufferCanvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
const bufferCtx = bufferCanvas.getContext( '2d' );
const reset = document.getElementById( 'reset' );

document.body.appendChild( canvas );

onRedraw();

redraw.addEventListener( 'click', onRedraw );
```

```css
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
button { position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 20px; z-index: 1; }
```

```html
<button id="redraw">Redraw</button>
```

If you'de rather use lose no data at all and 'rescale' the canvas the best it can, perhaps best to use something like this:

```js
/* This method does the resize by just redrawing the canvas from a buffer: */
function onResize( event ){
  
  bufferCanvas.width = canvas.width;
  bufferCanvas.height = canvas.height;
  bufferCtx.drawImage( canvas, 0, 0 );
  
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
  
  ctx.drawImage( bufferCanvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

}

/* This method is for drawing some content to help visualisation. */
function onRedraw(){
    
  const r = v => Math.floor(Math.random() * v);
  
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;

  ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${r(255)},${r(255)},${r(255)})`;
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight );
  ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${r(255)},${r(255)},${r(255)})`;
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2 );
  ctx.fillRect( innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2, innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2 );

}

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onResize );

const canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
const bufferCanvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
const bufferCtx = bufferCanvas.getContext( '2d' );
const reset = document.getElementById( 'reset' );

document.body.appendChild( canvas );

onRedraw();

redraw.addEventListener( 'click', onRedraw );
```

```css
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
button { position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 20px; z-index: 1; }
```

```html
<button id="redraw">Redraw</button>
```